# Swift iOS8.1 selector does not have a member named 'convertFromStringLiteral'

Tags: swift, selector, ibeacon, ios8.1

I used an iBeacon Library in Swift,

```
// Listening Notifications
func registerNotifications() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector.convertFromStringLiteral("handleNotification:"), name: kBUOYDidFindBeaconNotification, object: nil)
}
```

After used the iOS8.1 SDK, the editor said:

```
'Selector.Type' does not have a member named 'convertFromStringLiteral'
```

How can I solve this problem?
I tried the following code but not working.

```
 Selector("handleNotification:")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write the string without Selector:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "handleNotification:", name: kBUOYDidFindBeaconNotification, object: nil)
```